# How can I output data to a pdf onclick in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf

I'm trying to output an invoice to a pdf file. There are checkboxes that when checked will display the values in a modal after a button is clicked.

Currently, I have everything in a modal but would like the option to have it be viewed as a pdf as well. I've been trying to use the jspdf library  but have been receiving an error when clicking the button to display the modal + output data to a pdf. This is the error in the console when I click the button to display the modal/create a PDF

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
    at ServicesComponent.submit (services.component.ts:55)
    at ServicesComponent_Template_form_submit_8_listener (services.component.html:18)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15308)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15352)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:561)
```

This is my services.component.ts where the submit function is located

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ServiceHelper } from '../services.service';
import { ServiceItem } from '../services.interface';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Invoice } from '../invoice';
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from './../auth-layout/auth-layout.component';
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-services',
  templateUrl: './services.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./services.component.css']
})


export class ServicesComponent {

  @ViewChild("output", {
    static: true
  }) output: ElementRef;

  serviceItems: ServiceItem[];
  invoice: Invoice; //from invoice.ts

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private serviceHelper: ServiceHelper, private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {

    this.invoice = new Invoice();
    this.serviceItems = serviceHelper.getServices();
  }

  clearInvoice(): void {
    /**
     * Iterate over the beverages array and set each objects checked property to false.
     */
    for (let service of this.serviceItems) {
      service.checked = false;
    }

    this.invoice = new Invoice(); // return a new instance of the Bill object.
  }



  openSnackBar(message: string) {
    this._snackBar.open(message + " was added!");
  }

  //Opens modal with calculated results
  submit() {

    //Attempting to create pdf
    const DATA = this.output.nativeElement;
    const doc: jsPDF = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
    doc.html(DATA, {
      callback: (doc) => {
        doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
      }
    });


    console.log(this.serviceItems)


    for (let item of this.serviceItems) {
      if (item.checked) {
        this.invoice.addServiceItem(item);
      }
    }

    console.log(this.invoice.serviceItems);
    console.log(this.invoice.getTotal());


    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AuthLayoutComponent, {
      data: {
        invoice: this.invoice
      },
      disableClose: true,
      width: '800px'
    })


    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result === 'confirm') {
        alert('Your order has been processed!');
        this.clearInvoice();
      } else {
        alert('Your order has been canceled.');
        this.clearInvoice();
      }
    })
  }
}
```

here's my auth-layout.component.html that contains the modal markup

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Order Summary</h2>
<div mat-dialog-content id="output" #output>
    <div>
        <strong>Menu items:</strong>
        <div *ngFor="let item of invoice.serviceItems">
            &nbsp;{{ item.serviceName }} ({{item.servicePrice | currency}})
        </div>
        <br />
        Subtotal: {{ invoice.getTotal() | currency }}
    </div>

    <hr />

    <p>
    Labor Cost: {{ invoice.getLaborTotal() | currency }}
    </p>

    <hr />

    <p style="font-weight: bold;">Invoice total: {{ invoice.getInvoice() | currency }}</p>
</div>
```

and my auth-layout.component.ts file for the modal

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Invoice } from '../invoice';
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth-layout',
  templateUrl: './auth-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth-layout.component.css']
})
export class AuthLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  invoice: Invoice;

  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AuthLayoutComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: any) {
    this.invoice = data.invoice;
    console.log(this.invoice);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```